# Apache Proxy not pulling resource from correct path for Jenkins, Nexus, Sonarqube

Tags: apache, jenkins, sonarqube, reverse-proxy, nexus

I'm having an issue with my Apache Proxy server.
On my server, I have 3 services running + Apache Proxy
Jenkins (port 8082), Sonarqube (port 9000), and Nexus (port 8081)

My Apache Virtual Host configuration looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.katone.com

    ProxyPass           /jenkins    http://localhost:8082
    ProxyPassReverse    /jenkins    http://localhost:8082
    ProxyPass           /nexus      http://localhost:8081
    ProxyPassReverse    /nexus      http://localhost:8081
    ProxyPass           /sonarqube  http://localhost:9000
    ProxyPassReverse    /sonarqube  http://localhost:9000

    <Location "/jenkins">
      Require all granted
    </Location>
    <Location "/nexus">
      Require all granted
    </Location>
    <Location "/sonarqube">
      Require all granted
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I attempt to log onto my SonarQube for example, I get the following error in the Developer Console:

```
Loading module from “http://example.katone.com/js/vendors-main.m.8aed9dc9.chunk.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).
sonarqube
Loading module from “http://example.katone.com/js/main.m.6c3bf723.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).
```

It is looking at the wrong place.
When I change it to:
`http://example.katone.com:9000`

The resources are indeed there.

Any ideas on how to set my proxy to look at the correct path?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it!  HalleluYah!

This is what I ended up having to do (only showing you what I did on the Sonarqube one since that is the only one I did so far before replying to this post)

1. Edited SonarQube conf file:  ${SonarqubeDir}/conf/sonar.properties
2. Uncommented and set the 2 configuration as followed, setting the Base Url:

```
sonar.web.host=127.0.0.1
sonar.web.context=/sonarqube
```

3. Restarted Sonarqube

```
stopntservice
startntservice
```

4. Test to make sure the configuration was applied correct

```
// No longer works
localhost:9000

// Works now because of the conf base url change
localhost:9000/sonarqube
```

5. With the baseurl set, the Apache Proxy Virtual Host now looks like this:
   (Notice the "sonarqube" after the "localhost:9000")

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.katone.vi.com

    ...
    ...

    ProxyPass           /sonarqube  http://localhost:9000/sonarqube
    ProxyPassReverse    /sonarqube  http://localhost:9000/sonarqube

    <Location "/jenkins">
      Require all granted
    </Location>
    <Location "/nexus">
      Require all granted
    </Location>
    <Location "/sonarqube">
      Require all granted
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

6. Restart Apache after updating the VirtualHost

// Run following command in "${apacheDir}/bin/"

`httpd -k restart`

It worked for me.  I hope it helps someone in the future!

Comment: `<Location>` does not work when the sonarqube server is running via docker. And apache reverse proxy documentation says: `do not use <Location>`. I can't solve this!